# How to generate matlab workspace variable in matrix format

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matlab code that generate different combination between matrix. I am using it as part of a bigger script. Below is just example

```
A=[1,2,3,4];
B=[1,2,3,4];

for i=1:size(A,2);
    for j=1:size(B,2);           
C=[A(1,i),B(1,j)]

    end
end
```

It will generate different possible combination between Matrix A and Matrix B as below.

C =

```
 1     1
```

C =

```
 1     2
```

C =

```
 1     3
```

C =

```
 1     4
```

C =

```
 2     1
```

C =

```
 2     2
```

C =

```
 2     3
```

C =

```
 2     4
```

C =

```
 3     1
```

C =

```
 3     2
```

C =

```
 3     3
```

C =

```
 3     4
```

C =

```
 4     1
```

C =

```
 4     2
```

C =

```
 4     3
```

C =

```
 4     4
```

But in my workspace variable, C shows only (4,4) which is the last answer. How to do if I want to get all C answer in one big matrix as

```
1 1 
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4 
.... etc (which will be 16,2 matirx). Thanks.
```

Comment: See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-84906

Comment: a side note, you can (and in my view it is better to ) use linear indexing

Comment: Thanks for advices . I was trying to use "cat" function. It can concatenate matrix with different names, but I still cannot find how to concatenate output from one variables (in my case, concatenate C from every loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the matrix by using `C=[C;A(1,i),B(1,j)];`. Of course,that requires `C` to be initialized as an empty matrix. In your case, the final code is:

```
A=[1,2,3,4];
B=[1,2,3,4];
C=[];

for i=1:size(A,2);
    for j=1:size(B,2);           
     C=[C;A(1,i),B(1,j)];
    end
end
```